# I am not able to see the stdout and stderr log files in the tomcat/log directory?

Tags: windows, tomcat6

all the error messages are being displayed in console. i want the tomcat to print in log files stdout and stderr .. how to configure that?(i am using windows XP)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like windows will work the same as unix in the regard.

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true

So from a cmd window you'd have to do

```
statup.bat 1>out.log 2>err.log
```

Comment: this is not working.. it just shows environment variables and thats it.. doesnt show the log.

Comment: any other suggestions guys?

Comment: Okaym i'm not sure you can do that easily. The problem is that when you start tomcat it forks a java process to actually run tomcat in, hence you get a new console window appearing. You'd have to figure out how to get java running in process, which might be a little difficult. CWhy do you need it righting to stdout and sterr? Can't you just tail the log files in the logs dir?

Comment: how do i tail the log files in the logs dir? do u mean the tail command? i am on Windows XP

Comment: Have a look here http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/ for tail for windows.

Answer (score 1):

If started as a Windows service, you can configure the file locations for the stdout and stderr messages from the Service Manager.

[This link has a screenshot](http://codingexplorer.wordpress.com/2009/09/15/how-to-change-the-location-of-stdout-log/) and reference. See section **"Testing #2"**

Comment: no the tomcat 6 i downloaded isnt an installer.  i start the tomcat by double clicking the startup.bat file from the bin folder and an console opens that shows all the log statements.. how to redirect that to a stdout and stderr log files?